# Visual Studio Code Automatically adds useless code

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

`enter code here`I recently switched to VSC, installed python, pylance plugins. Everything seemed to be working fine, but when I started working with django, vsc started automatically when selecting an option in views.py CBV including Optional: str etc, for example `context_object_name: Optional[str]`

[Here I click Enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG06M.png)

[And then it automatically adds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loTiC.png)

I don't want to remove hints in the code and automatic addition, but I also don't want him to add unnecessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a new feature named **Inlay Type Hints** of Python extension in [July update](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-july-2022-release/#inlay-type-hints).

You can add the following line to your `setting.json` t o turn it off:

```
  "python.analysis.inlayHints.functionReturnTypes": false,
  "python.analysis.inlayHints.variableTypes": false,
```